# How to Sum by groups id and cat

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
username     counts     cat
Jo            1         A
Jo            5         B
Jo            1         C
An            2         A
An            3         B
An            2         C
```

My goal to get sum by username and when the cat = A and B then sum so the output like this

```
username     catcount     
Jo            6
Jo            1
An            5
An            2
```

My query

```
select username, sum(case when cat ='A' and cat ='B' then counts Else counts end ) as catcount
FROM tableA
group by username, cat
```

Not sure why not sum and need support here. Thank you.

Comment: The answer is in the GROUP BY but the syntax could be subject to RDBMS vendor-specific syntax or features. Can you elaborate on which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: How do you know if Jo's 6 is the count of A's and B's, or other characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` with a case expression that returns  'B' when the `cat` is 'A' (or 'A' when the `cat` is 'B'), this will consider A and B as a single group.

```
select username,
       sum(counts) counts
from tableA
group by username, case when cat ='A' then 'B' else cat end
order by username
```

Or you may use the case as the following:

```
select username,
       case when cat in ('A', 'B') then 'AB' else cat end cat,
       sum(counts) counts
from tableA
group by username, case when cat in ('A', 'B') then 'AB' else cat end
order by username
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/xMqYNfv8)

Comment: Excellent! Can u explian why cannot use case in select but in group? TY

Comment: You can use it in the select, I just tried to provide you with the expected output you posted. see the example in the demo https://dbfiddle.uk/ui84ZeZB

Comment: Great, if there is another cat D then i guess case when cat ='A' then 'B'  then 'C' else cat end. Correct?

Comment: I updated the answer, you may use the `IN` operator to consider similar cats as a single group.

Comment: Yay, Again thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that uses sub-Select, i.e. a Select statement inside a Select statement.

The inner Select statement changes the value of the 'cat' column to either 'AB' or 'C'. This is the heavy lifting.

The outer Select is a trivial application on Group By.

```sql
Select username, Sum(counts) as catcount, cat
From (Select username, counts, 'AB' cat
      From tableA
      Where cat = 'A' or cat = 'B'
      Union
      Select username, counts, cat
      From tableA
      Where Not (cat = 'A' or cat = 'B')
      ) Temp
Group By username, cat;
```